# Error while deploying Node Express app in Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, web-hosting, heroku-cli

I've been trying to deploy a node-express app in Heroku. I've created the app in Heroku, and try to open the app link which created at the end of the deployment. But it showing application error.
[screenshot of the error I got while running the app address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5bDe.png)

I think the error should be in the main route code.

[Error status when I ran the Heroku logs --tail.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwOUm.png)

Anyone gone through this earlier, help me to figure it out and resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you upload your project to a Git repository and send the link here?

Comment: Could you also please post the errors you're recieving as text on here? Images tend to go stale and they're also not searchable by others.